Why isn't the language updating when clicking the button in the LanguageSelector component using i18n?
I have a React application with internationalization support using the react-i18next library. The LanguageSelector component renders buttons for each available language, and when a button is clicked, it should update the language by calling i18n.changeLanguage(lng).
However, when I click the language buttons, nothing seems to happen. The language doesn't change, and the console.log statement inside the onClick handler is not being printed.
I've double-checked that the react-i18next library is properly configured and that the translations are loaded correctly. The rest of the application, including the Homepage component, is using the useTranslation hook to access the translations.
I believe there might be an issue with how the LanguageSelector component is integrated into the application or how the state is being managed, but I can't seem to figure out the root cause of the problem.
Can you help me identify why the language is not updating when the buttons are clicked and provide some guidance on how to resolve this issue?
import { useState } from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const lngs = {
    en: { nativeLanguage: 'English' },
    it: { nativeLanguage: 'Italiano' }
};

const LanguageSelector = () => {
    const { i18n } = useTranslation();

    return (
        <div className="btn-container">
            {Object.keys(lngs).map((lng) => (
                <button
                    type="button"
                    key={lng}
                    onClick={() => {
                        console.log(`Changing language to ${lng}`);
                        i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
                    }}
                    disabled={i18n.resolvedLanguage === lng}
                >
                    {lngs[lng].nativeLanguage}
                </button>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default LanguageSelector;

// src/pages/Homepage.js

import React, {useState, useEffect, useTransition} from 'react';

import '../css/Homepage.css';
import '../css/components/MapTimeline.css';

import { sDPTFetchFactoriesFL } from '../ArcGIS.js';
import { featureLayerServiceURLs, factoryStoryMapURLs } from '../GlobalConstants.js';
import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar.js';
import MapTimeline from '../components/TimelineMap/MapTimeline.js';
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import "../i18n.js";
import LanguageSelector from '../components/LanguageSelector.js'

function Homepage() {
    const [blurbOpacity, setBlurbOpacity] = useState(1);
    const [showScrollArrow] = useState(false);
    const [factories, setFactories] = useState([]);
    const [storymapURL, setStorymapURL] = useState('');
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

    // useEffect ==> init page and get all the factories to pass to TimelineGrid when page loads
    useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch factories FL when component mounts
        sDPTFetchFactoriesFL(featureLayerServiceURLs['Factory'])
        .then(factories => {     
            setFactories(factories);
            setStorymapURL(factoryStoryMapURLs.g);
        })
        // Handle errors
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching factories:', error);
        });
    }, []); // Empty dependency array

    // useEffect ==> blurb/title fade in and out logic
    useEffect(() => {
        
        const handleScroll = () => {
            const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;

            // Blurb fade in/out logic
            const blurbElement = document.getElementById('blurb');
            if (blurbElement) {
                const blurbHeight = blurbElement.offsetHeight;  // Get the blurb height offset
                const scrollThreshold = blurbHeight * 3;        // Threshold to start fade

                // Check the scroll position and update opacity as necessary
                if (scrollPosition < scrollThreshold) {
                    const opacity = 1 - scrollPosition / scrollThreshold;
                    setBlurbOpacity(opacity);
                } else {
                    setBlurbOpacity(0);
                }
            }
        };

        // Add an event handler to control the blur in/out  
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        };
    }, []);



    return (
        <div className="homepage">
            <LanguageSelector/>


            <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
                <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
                <title>Industrial Giudecca</title>
            </head>
            {/* Sidebar div */}
            <div><Sidebar/></div>

            {/* Title div ('blurb') */}
            <div id="blurb" style={{
                opacity: blurbOpacity,
                backgroundImage: 'url("front-image.jpeg")',
                backgroundSize: '100vw 100vh',
                backgroundAttachment: 'fixed'
            }} className={blurbOpacity <= 0 ? 'fade-out' : ''}>
                {/* Contains the logos on the top of the screen */}
                <div id='logos-container'>
                    <img id='main-logo' class='logo' src='logo.png'/>
                    <img id='wpi-logo' class='logo' src='wpi-logo.png'/>
                    <img id='sdpt-logo' class='logo' src='sdpt-logo.png'/>
                </div>

                {/* Overlay to darken the homepage front image; also contains the text for the landing screen */}
                <div className='bg-overlay'>
                    <div className="blurbRow" id="blurbTop">
                        <p className="blurbElm" id="blurbTitle">{t('blurbElmBlurbTitle')}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div className="blurbRow" id="blurbBottom">
                        <p className="blurbElm" id="blurbSubtitle">{t('blurbElmBlurbSubTitle')}</p>
                        <p className="blurbElm" id="blurbCredits">- Mario Isnenghi</p>
                    </div>

                    <div className="blurbRow" id="blurbScroll">
                        <p className="blurbElm" id="scrollText">{t('blurbElmScrollText')}</p>
                        <div className={`scrollArrow ${showScrollArrow ? 'show' : ''}`}></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            {/* Timeline container */}
            <div id="homepage-timeline"><MapTimeline factories={factories}/></div>

            {/* Container for the section header container */}
            <div id='section-header-container' style={{
                backgroundImage: 'url("header-bg-image.jpg"',
                backgroundSize: '100% 100%',
                backgroundAttachment: 'fixed'
            }}>
                <div className='section-header-overlay' id='section-header-overlay'/>
                <div className='sb-divider'>
                    <p className='section-header'>{t("deeperDive")}</p>
                    <p className='section-header'>{t("intoIndustrialHistory")}</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            {/* Storyboard iframe from ArcGIS */}
            <iframe src="https://storymaps.arcgis.com/stories/d6072e65094c49269316d897de0cb258?cover=false" width="100%"
                    height="1050v" frameBorder="0" allowFullScreen allow="geolocation"></iframe>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Homepage;

import i18n from "i18next";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import enHP from "./locals/en/Homepage.json";
import itHP from "./locals/it/Homepage.json";

i18n

    .use(initReactI18next)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .init({
       

        fallbackLng: "en",
        resources: {
            en: {
                translation: enHP
            },
            it: {
                translation: itHP
            }
        },
        returnObjects: true,
        debug: true
    });
export default i18n;

I have tried adding console log information in the onClick part of the LanguageSelector file but nothing is printed.

ChangeLanguage works by selecting a directory, can you please provide an image or show us where your translations are placed. For example my setup is /static/locales/USA/strings.json and static/locales/JPN/strings.json. So when I want to change the language I do this i18n.changeLanguage("USA") and the language changes

What does disabled={i18n.resolvedLanguage === lng} mean? Could it be that the button is always disabled? Can you explain the logic behind this?

My translations are stored in a /src/locals/en/Homepage.json and /src/locals/it/Homepage.json

The disabled={i18n.resolvedLanguage === lng} makes it so the selected language can not be clicked again.

What is your load path in i18n config? Is it possible to include that as well in your question? I think i18n does not know the load path when you change the language, that is my first assumption

Updated with the i18n config

I think it might be the ns I am not 100% sure, here is part of my config with namespace which works for me, try setting a default namespace  and fallback
      fallbackLng: 'USA',
      defaultNS: 'strings',
      //Need to add the language to initialize a starting language and namespace
      lng: 'USA',
      ns: 'strings',


This did not work for me, This is what I updated
fallbackLng: "en",
    defaultNS: 'Homepage',
    lng: "en",
    ns: 'Homepage',

